# How to escape html characters in long text area field

Tags: map, string, long-text-area, contentnote, richtext-notes

I have a requirement where i need to copy the contents of a contentnote to a longtextarea field called 'comments' using apex anonymous.

The issue is i am getting the following HTML characters

for each line breaks in the body of the content note. I want to hide these

tags but at the same time maintain the linebreaks!
enter image description here
[image]

my code converts the blob to a string and also displays HTML characters:-

```
List<ContentNote> cntNoteList = [SELECT Id,content,TextPreview FROM 
ContentNote WHERE Id in :noteId];
  Map<Id, String> cntMap = new Map<Id, String> ();
     for(ContentNote cn : cntNoteList){

      string s1 = cn.content.tostring();
//string s2 = SUBSTITUTE(JSINHTMLCODE(s1),'\\\n','<br/>')
// string s2 = s1.replaceAll('\\\n', '<br/>');
  String s2 = s1.stripHtmlTags();
cntMap.put(cn.Id , s2);
   }
```

Comment: Noticed that the same question being asked again, did you delete old one and created new one? Original question had a comment by sfdcfox asking to add more details. Such kind of activity is not nice to do. You should have patience and clarify the problem based on comments.

Answer (score -1):

Thank u so much for ur comments!
ButI have found the answer to my question. The linebreaks are removed now in a longtextarea field

```
 string s1 = cn.content.tostring();
   string s2 = s1.replace('<p>', ' ').replace('</p>','\r\n');  
     string s3 = s2.unescapeHtml4();
```

[image]